# JavaScript Asynchronous Loop does not return results

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, dojo

I was having some problem when trying to do a async function in JavaScript. Basically I have a pointArr to store the coordinates along the route. Then I got a moveNext() which takes in each coordinates along the route and plot onto the map. Then inside the moveNext(), I got another array which is busList. If the coordinates along the route match the coordinates of busList, then I minus the totalBusStopLeft by one. Here is the code where I call the moveNext():

```
 getAllBusLoc(function(busList) {
            //At first I set the totalBusLeft by the length of busList which is 13 in this case
            var totalBusLoc = busList.length;
            document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
                 timeout = 1500;
            pointArr.forEach(function(coord,index){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, totalBusLoc);
                }, timeout * index);
            });
        });

function moveNext(coordx, coordy, k, busList, totalBusLoc ){
//pointToCompare is the coordinates in the route but not the coordinates of busList
var pointToCompare = coordx + "," + coordy;

//If the coordinates in route matches the coordinate in busList, I minus busLeft by one
if(busList.indexOf(pointToCompare) > -1){
     parseFloat(totalBusLoc--);
             document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc ;

}

//Code to Add marker

}
```

However, with this code, my Html component busStopLeft keep showing 13 which is the original totalBusLoc. I wonder how could I return the minused totalBusLoc from moveNext(). Any ideas?

I have tried to use async.eachSeries but when I imported that async.js, it was giving me another error message which crash with dojo.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the part where I tried to use callback:

```
totalBusLoc = busList.length;
        document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
        timeout = 1500;
        pointArr.forEach(function(coord,index){
            setTimeout(function(busLeft){
                moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, totalBusLoc);
            }, timeout * index);
        });
    });


function moveNext(coordx, coordy, k, busList, totalBusLoc, callback){
var pointToCompare = coordx + "," + coordy;
 if(busList.indexOf(pointToCompare) > -1){
 parseFloat(totalBusLoc--);
 document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
 callback(totalBusLoc);
}
}
```

Comment: In the second one in the moveNext you calling the callback but not passing the callback thats why its crashing

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal So do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Within `moveNext()` you only update the local variable (parameter) `totalBusLoc`, a variable that disappears when the function ends. You'd need to remove that parameter and instead define it as a variable in the containing scope, so that it would retain its value between calls to `moveNext()`. Or read and parse the `.innerHTML` value from the `"busStopLeft"` element and increment *that*. (By the way, calling `parseFloat()` in this line: `parseFloat(totalBusLoc--);` doesn't do anything because you don't use the return value.)

Comment: @nnnnnn But I thought I pass it back via callback and then when it is in the forEach loop it will take the parameter and execute the minus again?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that `callback(totalBusLoc)`, but when you call the `moveNext()` function you aren't passing it a callback function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Because I not sure how to get the callback function which is the totalBusLoc from moveNext() from setTimeout.

Comment: Is the `moveNext()` function called from anywhere else in your code other than that `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Nope, it will only be called from the setTimeout(). Because I am trying to loop to each point along the route. If the point matches the busStopLoc, then I minus the bus stops left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing a `callback` parameter for your `moveNext()` function doesn't help if you don't actually pass a function when you call `moveNext()`. The code you've shown still only passes the original five arguments, so then when you try to use `callback(totalBusLoc)` you'll find that `callback` is `undefined`.

So you could change the call to `moveNext()` to pass a callback function:

```
moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, totalBusLoc, function(newTotalBusLoc) {
  totalBusLoc = newTotalBusLoc;
});
```

That should work because the function I've introduced has the original `totalBusLoc` variable in scope.

But it seems kind of messy, passing the value back and forth like that. Given that you confirmed in a comment that `moveNext()` isn't used anywhere else and doesn't contain much code I'd probably get rid of that function and move its body directly into the anonymous function that you pass to `setTimeout()`:

```
getAllBusLoc(function(busList) {           
    var totalBusLoc = busList.length;
    document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
    pointArr.forEach(function(coord,index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (busList.indexOf(coord.x + "," + coord.y) > -1)
                document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = --totalBusLoc;
        }, 1500* index);
    });
});
```

The inner anonymous function that you pass to `setTimeout()` has access to variables declared in its containing function(s), so it can access the outer `totalBusLoc` variable directly. That is, all three places that reference `totalBusLoc` in the code I've shown are referencing the *same* variable.

(Note: I also simplified your code a little. Where you had variables that were only used once after being assigned a value I got rid of those variables. But what I've shown should still do the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `async`:

```
  index = 0;
  async.eachSeries(pointArr, function(coord, moveNext){
      moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, totalBusLoc);
      index = index + 1;
    }, function(err){
      if( err ) {
        console.log('Failed');
    }
  });
```

Comment: With the async.eachSeries I needed to import the async.js. As I mentioned in the question above, the file is crashing with the dojo library

Comment: @Denise ahh okay missed that I guess.